# How to get Wolfram Alpha to draw two different plots on the same graph?

Tags: wolfram-alpha, graph

I want to draw this line:

> [ParametricPlot[{-2 (-5 + t), 5 + t}]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ParametricPlot%5B%7B-2+%28-5+%2B+t%29%2C+5+%2B+t%7D%5D)

And this circle, radius 25:

> [ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 25]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=ContourPlot%5Bx%5E2+%2B+y%5E2+%3D%3D+25%5D)

On the same graph.

No matter what combination I use, I can't get them overlaid on the same graph.

Is there any way to do this? I will also consider other web apps that may be able to do this.

Answer (score 3):

x= -2 (-5 + t)  (1)
y= 5 + t (2)

t = y - 5;

Substitute into (1)

y = -(1/2)x + 10

`ContourPlot[x^2 + y^2 == 25 , y == -(1/2)x + 10]`

You can also try the reverse and change to parametric. *That could be left as an exercise.*

Comment: This works also in Google search: enter `(25-x^2)^0.5,-(25-x^2)^0.5 ,-(1/2)x+10` in the search box and zoom out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Multiple Function Plotter](http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=1bd413de70f32142f4a33a94134c5690) widget.